# Graphql cache only updates in localhost not on the Vercel deployment

Tags: reactjs, graphql, serverless, apollo-client, vercel

Hello fellow developers,

I'm currently encountering an issue for which I haven't been able to find a solution. I'm in the process of building a brand new web application from scratch, utilizing modern tools and technologies, including:

Front-end:
TypeScript/React
Apollo GraphQL

Back-end:
Node.js
Apollo GraphQL

Deployment (Front-end/Back-end):
Vercel

Here's the problem I'm facing: I've been experimenting with various approaches to update the cache in the production environment, but so far, I've been unsuccessful. The only "workaround" I've discovered is to trigger refetch queries. However, due to the complex nature of the database calculations, it takes a considerable amount of time to update. As a result, I have to wait for 6000 ms (6 seconds) before executing the refetch queries. I've also implemented manual updates after the mutations that modify the cache, which works perfectly fine when testing locally but fails to function correctly on Vercel.

Let me provide some context on how the app functions. It involves listing mutable items, allowing users to add new items and modify existing ones. When a user opens and modifies an item, a request is sent to the back-end. Currently, I'm performing refetching of all queries after this update. However, due to the extensive time it takes, I'm forced to introduce a 6000ms delay before executing the refetch, otherwise, I encounter unexpected errors.

I would greatly appreciate your insights on finding a suitable solution to this problem. Why am I unable to update the cache on a published app hosted on Vercel? What alternative approaches can be considered to ensure smooth cache updates?

-Experimented with various approaches to update the cache in the production environment, but none have been successful. Like all the functions that can be used with cache.modify({}). I made it with createFramgments so writeFregmants, update fields after identification, read/update query. All works locally
-Discovered a temporary workaround by triggering refetch queries. However, the update process is time-consuming so I introduced a delay of 6000 ms (6 seconds) before executing the refetch queries to allow sufficient time for the updates to complete.
-Encountered issues with the manual updates not functioning properly on Vercel, the hosting platform for the published app.

Snippets:

```js
update(cache, {data}) {
                if (data?.editUser) {
                    const {editUser} = data
                    const {firstName, lastName, email} = editUser
                    cache.modify({
                        id: cache.identify(editUser),
                        fields: {
                            firstName() {
                                return firstName
                            },
                            lastName() {
                                return lastName
                            },
                            email() {
                                return email
                            },
                        },
                    })
                }
            },
            
update(cache, {data}) {
                if (data?.editUser) {
                    const {editUser} = data
                    cache.modify({
                        fields: {
                            search(existingUsers: Reference[] = []) {
                                const newUserReference = cache.writeFragment({
                                    data: editUser,
                                    fragment: gql`
                                        fragment NewFragment on User {
                                            firstName
                                            lastName
                                            email
                                        }
                                    `,
                                })
                                const mappedExistingUsers = existingUsers.map(
                                    (userReference: Reference) => {
                                        if (userReference.__ref === newUserReference?.__ref) {
                                            return newUserReference
                                        }

                                        return userReference
                                    }
                                )

                                return [...mappedExistingUsers]
                            },
                        }
                    })
                }
            },
```

Comment: You haven't shown any code how you try to update the cache. Could you please show come code? Also, most time you shouldn't need to refetch queries. Could you show an example query and mutation?

Comment: Hei,
I put now to update snippets. Thx to look at it. Both works in localhost. Isn't it som known issues with serverless apps that those cannot handle apollo InMemoryCache?

Comment: Apollo inMemoryCache runs in the browser of the user, not on Vercel or localhost, so it's definitely not that reason ;)

Comment: Although you should not do most of what you do there - for one, you modify your existing users objects directly instead of creating new versions of those, also you should probably not call `writeFragment` inside of `cache.modify`. 
I'm back to the question of "is any of this necessary at all"? And I would guess that it isn't. Again, could you show some queries and mutations? Those can auto-update your stuff for you if you write them correctly.

Comment: Hei,
THX, Can the problem be that I'm not receiving all the info in the mutation, only an id? 
export const CreateUserDocument = gql`
    mutation CreateUser($firstname: String!, $lastname: String!, $email: String!) {
  createUser(
    firstname: $firstname
    lastname: $lastname
    email: $email
  ) {
    id
  }
}

Comment: @phry This video also makes me confused about this. They also update the cache because the delete and the add does not work only with refetch queries.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhdGLMeXnvI

Comment: @phry and one more thing, so you are right. I don't have to update manually cache for edit mutation, but, it also only works locally. Madness. Updates the user after mutation just fine but after I publish it, it does nothing at all. :( So weird

Comment: It might make sense that you jump over into the Apollo Discord, and ask there again - things like that require a lot of back-and-forth and better solved in a chat.

Comment: @phry Ok. I'll do that, thx.